# Getting Error Unrecognized character escape 'S' in JUNIT json string

Tags: java, json

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized character escape 's' (code 83)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized character escape 'S' (code 83)
```

getting this error for  //s//S how to correct it

I tried ////s for small s but then getting error for capital S.

```
String uiConfigs1 = "[{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"CUACCI\",\"compSeq\":1,\"compName\":\"QuickFilterComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":1,\"rowSeq\":1,\"fieldType\":\"dropdown\",\"uiFieldName\":\"accFilterCriteria\",\"value\":\"F01#F02#F03#F04#F05\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"CUACCI\",\"compSeq\":1,\"compName\":\"QuickFilterComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":2,\"rowSeq\":1,\"fieldType\":\"dropdown\",\"uiFieldName\":\"accInstFilterCriteria\",\"value\":\"Response#CUACCI\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"accFilterCriteria#F01#F02#F03\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"CUACCI\",\"compSeq\":1,\"compName\":\"QuickFilterComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":3,\"rowSeq\":1,\"fieldType\":\"text\",\"uiFieldName\":\"filteraccountTitle\",\"value\":\"Regx#[\\s\\S]*\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"accFilterCriteria#F03\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"CUACCI\",\"compSeq\":1,\"compName\":\"QuickFilterComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":3,\"rowSeq\":1,\"fieldType\":\"text\",\"uiFieldName\":\"filteraccountNumber\",\"value\":\"Regx#^([0-9]|([0-9][0-9-/]{0,33}[0-9]))$\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"accFilterCriteria#F01\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"IRCAAL\",\"compSeq\":2,\"compName\":\"SectionTableComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":1,\"rowSeq\":0,\"fieldType\":\"label\",\"uiFieldName\":\"CheckBoxData#accNumber\",\"value\":\"frmtAccountNumber\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"IRCAAL\",\"compSeq\":2,\"compName\":\"SectionTableComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":1,\"rowSeq\":0,\"fieldType\":\"CheckBoxHeading\",\"uiFieldName\":\"chkBoxHeadingSelCol\",\"value\":\"\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"IRCAAL\",\"compSeq\":2,\"compName\":\"SectionTableComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":1,\"rowSeq\":0,\"fieldType\":\"ColumnHeading\",\"uiFieldName\":\"colHeadingAccTitleNumber\",\"value\":\"\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"IRCAAL\",\"compSeq\":2,\"compName\":\"SectionTableComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":1,\"rowSeq\":0,\"fieldType\":\"label\",\"uiFieldName\":\"CheckBoxData#accTitle\",\"value\":\"accountNLSTitle\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"IRCAAL\",\"compSeq\":2,\"compName\":\"SectionTableComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":2,\"rowSeq\":0,\"fieldType\":\"CheckBoxHeading\",\"uiFieldName\":\"ALWD\",\"value\":\"\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"IRCAAL\",\"compSeq\":2,\"compName\":\"SectionTableComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":2,\"rowSeq\":0,\"fieldType\":\"ColumnHeading\",\"uiFieldName\":\"colHeadingAlwd\",\"value\":\"\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"},{\"resourceId\":\"IRCA\",\"resourceClassification\":\"IRCAAL\",\"compSeq\":2,\"compName\":\"SectionTableComponent\",\"fieldSeq\":2,\"rowSeq\":0,\"fieldType\":\"checkbox\",\"uiFieldName\":\"CheckBoxData#ALWD\",\"value\":\"authCodeY\",\"active\":\"Y\",\"fieldDependency\":\"\"}]";
```

While running junit test case is succeed but its giving me error as above

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we have no context here - all you've provided is an exception and a single line of code which has over *3000* characters. If you could provide a [mcve] we'd have a much, much better chance of helping you.

Comment: *I tried ////s for small s but then getting error for capital S.*: then why not try the same thing for the capital S since it worked for the lowercase s?

Comment: \"value\":\"Regx#[\\s\\S]*\" Getting above error for this Regular expression in above line

Comment: JB because its not working for S .

Comment: if I do so for S then getting below warning
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.hsbc.hsbcnet.digital.ss.viewaccess.utils.ViewEntitlementsUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: These warnings have absolutely nothing to do with the JSON parsing. You don't have a Jackson parser exception, so the JSON parsing went fine. The fact that you have warnings related to the Log4J configuration is completely irrelevant.

Comment: but I am getting this log4j issue after making changes to regular expression

Comment: Again, if you could provide a [mcve], we could help you. But at the moment we have no idea where log4j fits into this at all (it sounds entirely irrelevant to the rest of the question) and we still don't know what any of your code looks like except a single string variable declaration.

Comment: Your test failed early with an exception because the encoding of backslashes was incorrect. You fixed the encoding of backslashes, so the test doesn't fail anymore, and thus executes more code, some apparently involving log4j. And there is no log4j configuration, so you get this log4j warning. The log4j warning has absolutely nothing to do with the encoding of backslashes in this JSON string. It's another, different, unrelated problem.

Comment: ok how to solve this log4j2 issue

Comment: First, you need to decide if it's really an issue to have Log4J use its default configuration. Then you read the warning message and click on the link it contains.

Comment: I solved this escape issue  using ////s////S .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this escape issue using ////s////S